# Digital signature show wrong sign date

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I am learning digital signature and how to sign it in c#.Here is my code:

Signature.cs

```
    public class Signature
    {
    static readonly string RT_OfficeDocument = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
    static readonly string OfficeObjectID = "idOfficeObject";
    static readonly string SignatureID = "idPackageSignature";
    static readonly string ManifestHashAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";

    // Entry Point
    public static void DigiSign(string tempfile)
    {
    // Open the Package    
        using (Package package = Package.Open(tempfile))
        {
            // Get the certificate
            X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate();
            SignAllParts(package, certificate);
        }
    }

    private static void SignAllParts(Package package, X509Certificate certificate)
    {
        if (package == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("SignAllParts(package)");
        List<Uri> PartstobeSigned = new List<Uri>();
        List<PackageRelationshipSelector> SignableReleationships = new List<PackageRelationshipSelector>();

        foreach (PackageRelationship relationship in package.GetRelationshipsByType(RT_OfficeDocument))
        {
            // Pass the releationship of the root. This is decided based on the RT_OfficeDocument (http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument)
            CreateListOfSignableItems(relationship, PartstobeSigned, SignableReleationships);
        }
        // Create the DigitalSignature Manager
        PackageDigitalSignatureManager dsm = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
        dsm.CertificateOption = CertificateEmbeddingOption.InSignaturePart;

        string signatureID = SignatureID;
        string manifestHashAlgorithm = ManifestHashAlgorithm;
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject officeObject = CreateOfficeObject(signatureID, manifestHashAlgorithm);
        Reference officeObjectReference = new Reference("#" + OfficeObjectID);

        try
        {
            dsm.Sign(PartstobeSigned, certificate, SignableReleationships, signatureID, new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject[] { officeObject }, new Reference[] { officeObjectReference });
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }

    }// end:SignAllParts()

    /**************************SignDocument******************************/
    //  This function is a helper function. The main role of this function is to 
    //  create two lists, one with Package Parts that you want to sign, the other 
    //  containing PacakgeRelationshipSelector objects which indicate relationships to sign.
    /*******************************************************************/
    static void CreateListOfSignableItems(PackageRelationship relationship, List<Uri> PartstobeSigned, List<PackageRelationshipSelector> SignableReleationships)
    {
        // This function adds the releation to SignableReleationships. And then it gets the part based on the releationship. Parts URI gets added to the PartstobeSigned list.
        PackageRelationshipSelector selector = new PackageRelationshipSelector(relationship.SourceUri, PackageRelationshipSelectorType.Id, relationship.Id);
        SignableReleationships.Add(selector);
        if (relationship.TargetMode == TargetMode.Internal)
        {
            PackagePart part = relationship.Package.GetPart(PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(relationship.SourceUri, relationship.TargetUri));
            if (PartstobeSigned.Contains(part.Uri) == false)
            {
                PartstobeSigned.Add(part.Uri);
                // GetRelationships Function: Returns a Collection Of all the releationships that are owned by the part.
                foreach (PackageRelationship childRelationship in part.GetRelationships())
                {
                    CreateListOfSignableItems(childRelationship, PartstobeSigned, SignableReleationships);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /**************************SignDocument******************************/
    //  Once you create the list and try to sign it, Office will not validate the Signature.
    //  To allow Office to validate the signature, it requires a custom object which should be added to the 
    //  signature parts. This function loads the OfficeObject.xml resource.
    //  Please note that GUID being passed in document.Loadxml. 
    //  Background Information: Once you add a SignatureLine in Word, Word gives a unique GUID to it. Now while loading the
    //  OfficeObject.xml, we need to make sure that The this GUID should match to the ID of the signature line. 
    //  So if you are generating a SignatureLine programmtically, then mmake sure that you generate the GUID for the 
    //  SignatureLine and for this element. 
    /*******************************************************************/

    static System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject CreateOfficeObject(
       string signatureID, string manifestHashAlgorithm)
    {
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(String.Format(Properties.Resources.OfficeObject, signatureID, manifestHashAlgorithm, "{3CF6B91E-C5F6-46A4-B036-72597274FCC0}"));
        System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject officeObject = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.DataObject();
        // do not change the order of the following two lines
        officeObject.LoadXml(document.DocumentElement); // resets ID
        officeObject.Id = OfficeObjectID; // required ID, do not change
        return officeObject;
    }
    /********************************************************/

    static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(certStore.Certificates, "Select a certificate", "Please select a certificate",
                X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
        return certs.Count > 0 ? certs[0] : null;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Signature.DigiSign(@"D:\abc.docx");
    }
}
```

And the file abc.docx after sign :
[image: link]

In the Additional Information of the signature , the system date/time(sign time) is diferrent from my local time and the date/time format too.I try to change my local time zone and reset date/time but it still not work.
What am i missing?

Comment: Maybe the time displayed in the dialog box is your time in UTC?

Comment: My time zone is GMT + 7.As you can see in my picture (link above),the signing time is not match with my local time in the taskbar.

Comment: `As you can see in my picture (link above),` Please provide that information in the text of your question. Many people (such as myself) won't click external links. When did you sign it? When does it say you signed it? What timezone do you live in?

Comment: @mjwills I signed it at 1:40 PM ,my time zone is UTC+07:00.After i run the code above,i open my document and view signature i signed in it.In the dialog box it say : the following additional information is stored within the signature : System Date/Time : 8:40 PM,which is wrong.

Comment: 1:40PM + 7 hours = 8:40PM

Comment: So am i have to change my time zone to UTC+00:00 ? no way.There must be some way to deal with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SecureBlackBox for .NET solve my problem !